# Develop selenium test case for flash application

Tags: flash, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have to do automation testing using selenium for flash application. After googling many sites, I didn't found any suitable information to develop it. So please provide me information about selenium for flash application and sample selenium testcases for flash application is more appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the following extension to your Selenium library:

https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/

This is also an additional extension that may come in handy for you depending on what you're doing with Flash:

https://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot automate Flash, because Selenium can only see DOM elements. Flash does not have a DOM.

You will need another library, to add to your Selenium library, that will be able to see Flash elements. One alternative is called Genie. I wrote an article a while back about how to use it, called "[Flash Light](http://www.professionaltester.com/magazine/backissue/pt021/)".